# How to manipulate multilevel nested data frames in R?

Tags: r, nested, tidyr, purrr

Imagine that there is a data frame `df`, which contains a nested data frame column `sub_df`. Each `sub_df` contains a nested data frame column called `sub_sub_df`. Each one of these also contain a nested data frame. etc. So we have a multilevel nested data frame, with an arbitrary number of levels.

If I want to calculate (`mutate`) something on the 3rd level e.g. `sub_sub_df`, what would be the best way to do this? I assume there is a function or notation, where I could manipulate giving the "address" of the level, which I would change.

I could use multiple levels of `mutate` inside `purrr::map` inside `mutate`. But the code will not be readable at all.

I wonder, if there is an easier and a cleaner way for such operations?

Here is an example data frame:

```
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(
    id = 1:8,
    sub_id = rep(1:2, each = 4),
    sub_sub_id = rep(1:2, each = 2, 2),
    sub_sub_sub_id = rep(1:8)
)

df = df %>% nest(sub_sub_sub_df = sub_sub_sub_id) %>%
    nest(sub_sub_df = c(sub_sub_id, sub_sub_sub_df)) %>%
    nest(sub_df = c(sub_id, sub_sub_df))
```